# How to join tables in EF LINQ

Tags: linq, join, entity-framework-ctp5

When I try to join tables

```
var query =
    from foo in db.Foos
    from bar in db.Bars
    where foo.ID == bar.FooID
    where foo.ID == 45
    select bar;


query.toArray()
```

I get such error

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Bar'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try that instead:

```
var query =
    from foo in db.Foos
    join bar in db.Bars on foo.ID equals bar.FooID
    where foo.ID == 45
    select bar;
```

Anyway, I suggest you model the relation between Foo and Bar in the EDM designer, this way you don't need an explicit join:

```
var query =
    from foo in db.Foos
    where foo.ID == 45
    from bar in foo.Bars
    select bar;
```

Comment: will modeling the relation in EDM designer create a foreign key in the database also?

Comment: how to convert it to LINQ Method-Based? I don't have idea how to convert `from bar in foo.Bars` using Method-Based

Comment: @Willy `db.Foos.Where(foo => foo.ID == 45).SelectMany(foo => foo.Bars)`