# How to do a JOIN in EF when the join condition is a like

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

I have the following SQL query I would like to convert into a EF Linq query, and I don't know how I can write the "like" part.

```
SELECT DepartmentsWithChildren.*
FROM dbo.People
    INNER JOIN dbo.DepartmentPersons
        ON DepartmentPersons.Person_Id = People.Id
    INNER JOIN dbo.DepartmentsWithChildren
        ON DepartmentsWithChildren.lvl LIKE '%,' + CAST(DepartmentPersons.Department_Id AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',%'
WHERE UserId = '01cb89b4-9f81-4012-a4d9-5a38468a7433'
```

Example result from the above query

```
Id  ParentDepartmentId  lvl
58  27  ,27,3,1,
64  27  ,27,3,1,
67  27  ,27,3,1,
77  27  ,27,3,1,
90  27  ,27,3,1,
93  27  ,27,3,1,
100 27  ,27,3,1,
102 27  ,27,3,1,
106 27  ,27,3,1,
134 27  ,27,3,1,
137 27  ,27,3,1,
396 27  ,27,3,1,
414 27  ,27,3,1,
171 67  ,67,27,3,1,
206 67  ,67,27,3,1,
219 67  ,67,27,3,1,
```

To clarify, I want to know how to do a LIKE part of a JOIN, I'm aware that in a WHERE clause I can use contains, but for JOINS, every example I find only uses equality, f.eks: [How to join tables in EF LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112183/how-to-join-tables-in-ef-linq)

Comment: What does `,67,27,3,1,` mean exactly? _CSV data in a database is usually a bad thing._

Comment: lvl is generated by a view query, and is a comma separated list of all the departments parent departments. So in this list department 171, has 4 parent departments (67,27,3,1)

Comment: A possible alternative way of doing this would be to have a separate table. Let's call it `MultiLevelParents`. It would have three columns - `Id`, `AncestorDepartmentId`, `Generation`. And instead of having the `lvl` value of `67,27,3,1` you would have four values in `MultiLevelParents` - the first being `171` and `67` and `1` and the last being `171` and `1` and `4`.

Comment: @mjwills that is one way to do this if I was willing to change the database. I could also simply use the above query as view and select from that. What I'm asking for is if this is possible to do in EF

Comment: @lsma I know how to do this in SQL but I really don't know where to start on how to do it in EF, that's why there is no example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use the equals operator when using join in Linq, below is a possible workaround.

Assuming your `DbContext` is called db:

```
var result = from people in db.People
             from departmentWithChildren in db.DepartmentsWithChildren
             join departmentPerson in db.DepartmentPersons 
                             on people.Id equals departmentPerson.Person_Id
              where departmentWithChildren.Any(d => d.lvl.Contains("," + 
                             departmentPerson.Deparment_Id + ",")) &&
                             people.UserId = "01cb89b4-9f81-4012-a4d9-5a38468a7433"
              select departmentWithChildren;
```

Comment: The question is how to do this in a join, not how to write a like query.

Comment: No, I'm asking how to do a LIKE JOIN, not a LIKE query

Comment: Ended up dropping the JOIN altogether, using simply 2 FROM clauses with a WHERE clause on the second referencing the first. I think this is refered to as a LEFT OUTER JOIN in EF

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna propose that too but it will generate a slightly less efficient query. It doesn't matter if you don't have millions of records ;) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A good and easy way is to do it with two linq queries.

```
var dict = from row in entities.departments where yada yada select row.Id;

var query = from row in entities.departmentpersons where
            dict.Contains(row.departmentId)
            select row;
```